# Find the sum $\frac2{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}+\frac2{\sqrt4+\sqrt8}+\frac2{\sqrt6+\sqrt{10}}+\ldots+\frac2{\sqrt{60}+\sqrt{64}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, telescopic-series

If the sum of the series

$$\frac2{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}+\frac2{\sqrt4+\sqrt8}+\frac2{\sqrt6+\sqrt{10}}+\ldots+\frac2{\sqrt{60}+\sqrt{64}}=\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}+{C}$$

Find the value of $A+B$

Okay, this series is actually a tough one for me. I don't know at all how to approach this question.
I would be really glad if someone will help me with this question

Comment: Do A, B and C have to be whole numbers ?

Comment: Yes @WW1..............

Comment: Easy to guess or not, it's guess work, not mathematics. Please, provide an exact expression for your sum, not just an example with a vague "$\ldots$".

Comment: A suggestion is better than nothing.. even if it is vague, for its encouraging spirit...It sets the questioner thinking for a solution especially when there are no other answers or comments available.

Comment: Is my edit okay? This seemed more plausible then the last edit,but if last edit was what you intended feel free to re roll or let me know so I can re roll.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{30} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2i}+\sqrt{2i+4}}&=\sqrt{2} \sum_{i=1}^{30} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i+2}}\\
&=\sqrt2 \sum_{i=1}^{30}\frac{\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i+2}}{i-(i+2)}
\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{30}(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i+2})
\end{align}

You should be able to complete the problem using telescoping sum.